# Please explain this Python based FTP server code

Tags: python, ftp, ftp-server, python-sockets

I was looking for FTP server implemented in Python and came across this https://gist.github.com/scturtle/1035886 . I tried to understand it but being a web developer and fairly new Python I found it confusing.

**Here's what I don't understand :**

1. **From where did this attribute appeared , Its not defined anywhere** 
    *Line no : 22, 23*

   ```
   def run(self):
       self.conn.send('220 Welcome!\r\n')
   ```
2. **Where is this function / code defined ?**
    *Line no : 223, 224*

   ```
   ftp.daemon=True
   ftp.start()
   ```

I know basic **OOP in Python** any **reference material to understand the code and become more power Python programmer will be appreciable** . Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(1) The variable is defined in `__init__`

```
def __init__(self,(conn,addr)):
    self.conn=conn
    ...
```

(2) FTPserverThread inherits from threading.Thread. The attribute and method are defined in the parent class.

When puzzling through code that uses the standard python library, it helps to [read the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/index.html). Search for "threading" and read away.

Comment: So from where is .send() inherited ? Sockets i think please explain.

Comment: line 214 `th=FTPserverThread(self.sock.accept())` creates the thread and passes in 1 argument - the result of calling `self.sock.accept`. `self.sock` is a socket and the [socket documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html?highlight=socket#module-socket) tells you that it returns a (conn, address) tuple, _where conn is a new socket object_. So, going back to the socket documentation, you see it has a `send` method.

Answer (score 0):

In an assignment, python will create the attribute (variable) if not present. So in `init` it actually does `self.conn=conn` to create the attribute. `__init__` is pretty much the constructor that is called when an instance of the class is made. Same for `ftp.daemon`. Now, `ftp.start()` is inherited from `threading.Thread`.

Comment: So from where is ```.send()``` inherited ? Sockets i think please explain.